# Is it possible to reassign Alt-H keyboard shortcut in Qt Creator?

Tags: editor, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

Is it possible to reassign <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> keyboard shortcut in Qt Creator? How it could be done?

Note: it calls Help menu item by default